Example orthonormal basis of Word Embedding Space?
Models such as Word2Vec supposedly provide a bijection between language tokens and some "latent-space" that is in fact a high-dimensional vector space.
If this is a vector space, it should be possible to provide an example of:

The dimension of the vector space
An orthonormal or quasi-orthonormal basis (i.e. a set of tokens $\{t_i\}$ such that $\mathrm{Word2Vec}(t_i)$ is approximately an orthonormal basis in latent space

However I can't find this in the literature for any model I'm familiar with

It's true that the vector space will have a dimension. It's also true that it will have orthonormal bases. But it's not necessarily true that we can find a set of tokens such that their vector representations will approximately form a basis. Tokens will tend to be correlated. A basis in this space will be vectors consisting, in general, of linear combinations of (the vectors associated with) many tokens. (As many tokens as there are dimensions in the space).

Oh! I meant to say "such that their vector representations will approximately form an orthonormal basis". Of course, pick as distinct tokens as you have dimensions and there's a basis (generically).
